# Airflow - No task dependency specified

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say - I have 3 different tasks in a DAG.

1. What happens if the task dependencies are not specified at all? What will be their order of execution? Will they execute in random order which can be different for every DAG run?
2. What if I want only one of these several tasks to execute? i.e. though 3 tasks are defined in the DAG, I want only one of them to be executed. Is this possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if the task dependencies are not specified at all? What will be their order of execution? Will they execute in random order which can be different for every DAG run?

Assuming you're not using the SequentialExecutor and there are available slots (Pool slots, worker concurrency, and parallelism), each task will execute roughly at the same time.

> What if I want only one of these several tasks to execute? i.e. though 3 tasks are defined in the DAG, I want only one of them to be executed. Is this possible? If yes then how?

You'd need to establish dependencies between the tasks or separate the tasks into different DAGs.

Answer (score 0):

1: They will have a flat layout, and all of them will be scheduled immediately.

2: I assume you mean that there is some condition that dictates which of the 3 tasks should be triggered, otherwise you should just remove the tasks from the DAG if they shouldn't be ran. To selectively run one of the 3 tasks look into the BranchPythonOperator. It takes a python function and it will skip any immediate downstream tasks that don't have their task ids returned by the python function.